# How to make a spiral rotate?

Tags: rotation, processing, increment, spiral

I have successfully coded a static spiral using lines, and now I'm supposed to make the spiral rotate from frame to frame. I tried incrementing the angle used for the `x` and `y` positions of the end of the lines with each frame, but the spiral doesn't move at all.

```
void draw() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 15 * NUM_LINES; i++) {
        float lineEndX = width / 2 + radius * cos(angle + startAngle);
        float lineEndY = height / 2 + radius * sin(angle + startAngle);
        line (lineStartX, lineStartY, lineEndX, lineEndY);
        lineStartX = lineEndX;
        lineStartY = lineEndY;

        radius = radius + 0.047;
        angle += 0.01 % (TWO_PI * NUM_TURNS);
    }
    startAngle += START_ANGLE_CHANGE;
    angle = 0;
}
```

Comment: Language used? External libraries/classes used? What is the type of `startAngle`, `angle` and `radius`, and what is the function `line`?

Comment: it says processing, thats a language.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] instead of a disconnected snippet.

Comment: I would suggest printing `startAngle` at the beginning of the loop, to ensure it's incrementing.  I suspect that it's resetting to zero each time.

Comment: @JamesK I tried your suggestion, and in fact startAngle is incrementing with every frame.

Comment: Add `background(255)` to your draw loop so that you can actually see what is happening. Add `frameRate(1)` to slow things down. Are you just drawing along the same spiral path over an over with incrementally rotated starting points?

Answer (score 1):

Add `background(255);` to your `draw` function. Also define `lineStartX`, `lineStartY` and `radius` there so their values are reset every time the function is called.

```
void draw() {
    background(255);
    float lineEndX = width / 2;
    float lineEndY = height / 2;
    float radius = 5;

    for (int i = 0; i < 15 * NUM_LINES; i++) {
        float lineEndX = width / 2 + radius * cos(angle + startAngle);
        float lineEndY = height / 2 + radius * sin(angle + startAngle);
        line (lineStartX, lineStartY, lineEndX, lineEndY);
        lineStartX = lineEndX;
        lineStartY = lineEndY;

        radius = radius + 0.047;
        angle += 0.01 % (TWO_PI * NUM_TURNS);
    }
    startAngle += START_ANGLE_CHANGE;
    angle = 0;
}
```

[Working example here](https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/spinning-spiral/6174003790544896).